# How to Parse JSON array in side JSON Array Android

Tags: android, json, arrays

i am working on json parsing. 
i am getting response in form of JSON Array and in side JSON Array another JSON array.
i am not getting hot parse this. getting json array object in side json array i am new in json so please need help.

here is my response:-

```
      [
        [
            {
                "Postcode": "BR6 0NH",
                "Notes": null,
                "Name": "Tesco Pharmacy (Orpington), Bromley, London",
                "Phone": "01689 307447",
                "Address": "10 AUGUSTUS LANE, ORPINGTON",
                "ServiceId": 0,
                "Capacity": null,
                "URL": null,
                "Error": null
            },
            {
                "Postcode": "DA14 5BN",
                "Notes": null,
                "Name": "Tesco Pharmacy, (Edgington Way), Bromley, London",
                "Phone": "0208 258 9447",
                "Address": "EDGINGTON WAY, SIDCUP",
                "ServiceId": 0,
                "Capacity": null,
                "URL": null,
                "Error": null
            }
        ]
      ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way

```
 try {
            JSONArray mainArry = new JSONArray(strJsonResponse);
            JSONArray contentArray = mainArry.getJSONArray(0);
            for (int i =0 ;i<contentArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject item = contentArray.getJSONObject(0);
                System.out.println("Postcode : " + item.getString("Postcode"));
                System.out.println("Notes : " + item.getString("Notes"));
                System.out.println("Phone : " + item.getString("Phone"));
                System.out.println("Address : " + item.getString("Address"));
                System.out.println("ServiceId : " + item.getString("ServiceId"));
                System.out.println("Capacity : " + item.getString("Capacity"));
                System.out.println("URL : " + item.getString("URL"));
                System.out.println("Error : " + item.getString("Error"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
String jsonResponse = "[[{\"Postcode\":\"BR6 0NH\",\"Notes\":null,\"Name\":\"Tesco Pharmacy (Orpington), Bromley, London\",\"Phone\":\"01689 307447\",\"Address\":\"10 AUGUSTUS LANE, ORPINGTON\",\"ServiceId\":0,\"Capacity\":null,\"URL\":null,\"Error\":null},{\"Postcode\":\"DA14 5BN\",\"Notes\":null,\"Name\":\"Tesco Pharmacy, (Edgington Way), Bromley, London\",\"Phone\":\"0208 258 9447\",\"Address\":\"EDGINGTON WAY, SIDCUP\",\"ServiceId\":0,\"Capacity\":null,\"URL\":null,\"Error\":null}]]";

try{
   JSONArray jsonOuterArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
   for (int i = 0 ;i<jsonOuterArray.length();i++){
       JSONArray jsonInnerArray = jsonOuterArray.getJSONArray(i);
       for (int j=0;j<jsonInnerArray.length();j++){
           HashMap<String,String> row = new HashMap<String, String>();
           row.put("Postcode",jsonInnerArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("Postcode"));
           row.put("Notes",jsonInnerArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("Notes"));
           row.put("Name",jsonInnerArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("Name"));
           row.put("Phone",jsonInnerArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("Phone"));
           row.put("Address",jsonInnerArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("Address"));
           row.put("ServiceId",jsonInnerArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("ServiceId"));
           row.put("Capacity",jsonInnerArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("Capacity"));
           row.put("URL",jsonInnerArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("URL"));
           row.put("Error",jsonInnerArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("Error"));
           data.add(row);
        }
   }

for (HashMap<String,String> row : data){
    System.out.print("Postcode : "+row.get("Postcode"));
    System.out.print("Notes : "+row.get("Notes"));
    System.out.print("Name : "+row.get("Name"));
    System.out.print("Phone : "+row.get("Phone"));
    System.out.print("Address : "+row.get("Address"));
    System.out.print("ServiceId : "+row.get("ServiceId"));
    System.out.print("Capacity : "+row.get("Capacity"));
    System.out.print("URL : "+row.get("URL"));
    System.out.print("Error : "+row.get("Error"));
}

}catch (Throwable e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Easily do it using gson library.Here is the code sample:
Your Entity Class will like:

```
public class ResponseEntity {
    @SerializedName("Postcode")
    public String Postcode;
    @SerializedName("Notes")
    public String Notes;
    @SerializedName("Name")
    public String Name;
    @SerializedName("Phone")
    public String Phone;
    @SerializedName("Address")
    public String Address;
    @SerializedName("ServiceId")
    public int ServiceId;
    @SerializedName("Capacity")
    public String Capacity;
    @SerializedName("URL")
    public int URL;
    @SerializedName("Error")
    public int Error;
}
```

Now Convert your json Array using GSON library.

```
Gson gson=new Gson();    
ResponseEntity[] entities = gson.fromJson(yourResponseAsString.toString(),
      ResponseEntity[].class);
```

Now you have the entity array at entities.
Thanks.